# How to get a "scoring" trained model(predict)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, grid-search

There is data (X, y) on which the search and training in the function GridSearchCV.
Training takes place on a custom criterion T_scorer.
Is it possible in the T_scorer function to get a trained model to use?
I need to "T_scorer" predict data "X1".
That is, the model is trained on data (X,y) at each iteration, and is predicted on (X1,y1)
Again (X1, y1) do not participate in training at all and "GridSearchCV" these data do not see.

Ideally, we should make the training to take place on the data(X,y), and in "scoring" the results based on predictions (X1,y1) should be transmitted)

```
def T_scorer(y_true, y_pred, clf, **kwargs):
    r = np.sum((y_pred == 0) & (y_pred == y_true))

    y_pred1 = clf.predict(X1)  #It doesn't work

    confmat = confusion_matrix(y, y_pred)
    print(confmat)
    print(r)
    return r

_scorer = make_scorer(T_scorer)

clf = RandomForestClassifier()
grid_searcher = GridSearchCV(clf, parameter_grid, cv=StratifiedKFold(shuffle =True,random_state=42),verbose=20, scoring=_scorer)
grid_searcher.fit(X, y)
clf_best = grid_searcher.best_estimator_
print('Best params = ', clf_best.get_params())
```

Comment: I want to calculate the parameter in this function. And send it to "return". This is ideal. But, it is suitable if you just output in" print " on each iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make_scorer()` should be used only when you have a function of the signature `(y_true, y_pred)`. When you use the `make_scorer()` on your function, the returned signature is:

func(estimator, X, y)

which is then used in the GridSearchCV. So instead of using `make_scorer`, you can specify your function as:

```
# I am assuming this is the data you want to use
X1 = X[:1000]
y1 = y[:1000]

def T_scorer(clf, X, y):
    # Here X and y passed on to the function from GridSearchCV will not be used
    y_pred1 = clf.predict(X1)
    r = np.sum((y_pred1 == 0) & (y1 == y_pred1))
    confmat = confusion_matrix(y1, y_pred1)
    print(confmat)
    return r

# Now dont use make_scorer, pass directly
grid_searcher = GridSearchCV(clf,..., verbose=20, scoring=T_scorer)
```

Comment: Works. Why the functions "T_scorer(cf, X, y)" and not "T_scorer(cf, X1, y1)"? In advance am asking understand, so as little experience)

Comment: @user287629 The parameters in the function will be passed from the GridSearchCV. You can name them anything. But then they wont be the ones you want them to be.

Comment: Is it possible in addition to this, to output results with (X, y) only in " print"?

Comment: @user287629 Yes. Just use X and y in the same way I used X1 and y1